# How do I refer to these lights?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

I know a bit of photography. If you decrease the number of shutter speed, the amount of light going into the lens increases and as a result of that, the lights become 'lines'.

How do I refer to such lights? I want to say -

I love ________ in this picture

OR

If you want to have _____ lights, decrease the shutter speed of your camera.

Here is what I'm referring to.

[image: lights in the night]

One word that comes to my mind is 'shredded lights'. Kindly confirm or suggest something better.

Comment: These are termed *light trails* in the jargon of photography, I believe. You could try googling "long exposure light trails". In common parlance people might also refer to them as *light streaks*.

Comment: You could try Google Images for "light trails".

Comment: That is the answer. Pls put it on. @DanBron

Comment: Oh yes...that's the word @DamkerngT.

Comment: @MaulikV I'm on my phone and will find it hard to submit an answer with proper research and sources, etc. If Damkerng finds it convenient, maybe he can post an answer.

Comment: True that. @DamkerngT. pls do the honor! :)

Comment: I still have something to take care of, could be a bit busy for a few more hours. (I only drop in periodically.) Also, I don't really know much about photography. I'd better leave it to Dan Bron. He posted his comment before me anyway. ;-)

Comment: So there are actually two kinds of 'light lines' in your example.  There are light trails on cars and there is lens flare on streetlights.  Only the lens flare could be described as being caused by the "amount of light".  The light trails are not caused by that at all, they are a consequence of sources moving during the long exposure time.  Just think of the Picasso 'drawing with light' pictures.

Comment: I would call those 'tracers', but I'm not a photographer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Photographers call those lines 'light trails'. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=light%20trail) for "light trail" makes this quite apparent.

Here are the top two results:

1. [5 Advanced Tips for Light Trail Photography](http://digital-photography-school.com/5-advanced-tips-light-trail-photography/)
2. [How to Shoot Light Trails](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-shoot-light-trails/)

Other possible terms include "[light tracers](https://www.google.com/search?q=light%20tracers&safe=off&biw=1440&bih=807&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=DPNxVaSIAYaiyQSig4DYAQ&ved=0CEwQsAQ)" and "[light streaks](http://light%20streaks)".